# How to check if last email sent was successfully delivered or not using MIME::Lite perl

Tags: perl, email, mime

I wanted to send emails in perl code. So I used [`MIME::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite) module.

I am able to send emails as I wanted if I removed last_send_successful check, else I get error mentioned below.I want to know if the email was sent successfully. Below is the code snippet I used.

```
sub sendEmailWithCSVAttachments {
    my $retries        = 3;
    my $retry_duration = 500000;    # in microseconds
    my $return_status;
    my ( $from, $to, $cc, $subject, $body, @attachments_path_array );

    $from                   = shift;
    $to                     = shift;
    $cc                     = shift;
    $subject                = shift;
    $body                   = shift;
    @attachments_path_array = shift;

    my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
        From    => $from,
        To      => $to,
        Cc      => $cc,
        Subject => $subject,
        Type    => 'multipart/mixed'
    ) or die "Error while creating multipart container for email: $!\n";

    $msg->attach(
        Type => 'text',
        Data => $body
    ) or die "Error while adding text message part to email: $!\n";

    foreach my $file_path (@attachments_path_array) {

        my $file_name = basename($file_path);
        $msg->attach(
            Type        => 'text/csv',
            Path        => $file_path,
            Filename    => $file_name,
            Disposition => 'attachment'
        ) or die "Error while adding attachment $file_name to email: $!\n";
    }

    my $sent = 0;
    while ( !$sent && $retries-- > 0 ) {

        eval { $msg->send(); };

        if ( !$@ && $msg->last_send_successful() ) {
            $sent = 1;
        } else {
            print "Sending failed to $to.";
            print "Will retry after $retry_duration microseconds.";
            print "Number of retries remaining $retries";
            usleep($retry_duration);
            print "Retrying...";
        }
    }

    if ($sent) {
        my $sent_message = $msg->as_string();
        print "Email sent successfully:";
        print "$sent_message\n";
        $return_status = 'success';
    } else {
        print "Email sending failed: $@";
        $return_status = 'failure';
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Can't locate object method "last_send_successful" via package "MIME::Lite"
```

This means this method is not present. But it is given in the reference I am using.

1. So am I missing something or is there alternative to check if the last send was successful or the reference I am using is incorrect?
2. Is this check redundant as I am already using eval block?
3. Will using eval catch the error of email not getting delivered? (Most probably no but want to confirm)
4. How to make sure that email is delivered with MIME::Lite?

Comment: perl -MMIME::Lite -e 'print $MIME::Lite::VERSION'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use the `eval` block or do anything fancy to ensure that the mail has been sent; that is what `last_send_successful` is for. When the send subroutine successfully completes its work, it sets an internal variable (`$object->{last_send_successful}`); this is what the `last_send_successful` sub is checking. It is usually not necessary to use an `eval` block unless you are trying to prevent a script dying or throwing a runtime or syntax error.

You can simplify your code to something like the following:

```
$msg->send;

if ($msg->last_send_successful) {
    # woohoo! Message sent
}
else {
    # message did not send.
    # take appropriate action
}
```

or

```
$msg->send;

while (! $msg->last_send_successful) {
    # message did not send.
    # take appropriate action
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am using "use MIME::Lite" at the top. Then also I am getting same error. If I would not have used the "use MIME::Lite", I would not have been able to create a MIME message itself.

Comment: If you dump the contents of `$msg`, does the internal variable `$object->{last_send_successful}` show up? You might have discovered a bug in the module. What versions of MIME::Lite and Perl are you using?

Comment: The version of MIME::Lite I am using is 3.027. That is the reason for this error. With version 3.030, it doesn't give the object missing error. Anyways thanks folks.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the email delivered successfully ??

Comment: Send some test messages and check whether or not they get delivered? The perl module is a wrapper round whatever backend you're using (sendmail, SMTP, some custom subroutine, etc.). If the backend reports that the message was delivered successfully, `last_send_successful` will return `1`. This only covers the actual email dispatch; you can send an email to a bogus address and the backend will happily report that the send was successful.